# Dynamically changing header text depending on URL in Wordpress html page

Tags: headers

My shopping cart displays the order history on the last page the customer visited.  For example, www.someurl.com/item1 is the last page the customer visited before checkout.  An order confirmation email is sent with a link to that order as well as the customers entire order history.  The link address is www.someurl.com/item1/#!/~/orderConfirmation.

I would like my header to read "item1" on www.someurl.com/item1, and "history" on www.someurl.com/item1/#!/~/orderConfirmation.

I am using Wordpress 3.5.2 with a twenty-twelve child theme

Can this be accomplished?  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: "Header" can mean different things to different people, write or wrong. What _exactly_ do you mean? What shopping cart do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I got to work.  I don't know if it's the most efficient method, but this is what I did:  Also, for whatever reason I couldn't get it do display my header (custom page title) when I declared the variable within the same script.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated, but please keep in mind I'm an old Cobol programmer.  I have trialed and errored my way through this website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myurl=document.URL;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (myurl == "http://URL/alabama-jumpers/#!/~/orderConfirmation")
    {null}
else    
if (myurl == "http://URL/alabama-jumpers/#!/~/orders/offset=0") 
    {null}
else
    {document.write("<span style=\"color: #5d0800; font-family: 'Marcellus SC'; font-size: 32px; font-weight: 300; text-align: left;\">Alabama Jumpers<\/span>")}
</script>
```